# How can I fold sections containing include commands in TeXMaker?

Tags: sectioning, texmaker, code-folding

I have used Emacs to edit my .tex files and I got used to the fold/unfold option.
I am back to TeXMaker for some time and I would like to also fold/unfold sections, subsections and so on. This can be accomplished for the sections using the '-' appearing in the side bar when the pointer is in the line of the `\section` command. But this does not work with the subsection or (most importantly) with the sections containing an `\include` command.

Do you have a solution for that? How can I fold/unfold any sections or subsections in TeXMaker?

Bonus: Does a shortcut exist for that?

Comment: i'm not a texmaker user, so i can't address the folding issue. but i think you'd be better off using `\input` instead of `\include`.  `\include` is usually used at the chapter level or above, since it always starts a new page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Actually the use of `\include` I have does not start a new page... I only use it to include .tex files containing tikz pictures created with matlab2tikz.

Comment: okay.  i made an assumption that the `\include` you mentioned was the "standard" one, but clearly it's not.  thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You don't have code folding feature for `\include` it's only available for [`\part, \chapter, \section,.., \begin{foo} \end{foo}`](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION301). Place a feature request with clear demo at [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list). `Off-topic`: Use `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzsetnextfilename{figure-name}` as shown in http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/ to speedup tikzpic compilation for second run and navigate via `Structure` Menu left pane of editor or fold at `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: @texenthusiast Ok! Thanks for the links. I will post a feature request as soon as possible and learn how to speed up tikz pictures compilation (which can sometimes b really painful!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Texmaker, there is no code folding feature for `\include` it's only available for `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`,.., `\begin{foo} \end{foo}`. Place a feature request with clear demo at [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list).

Note:
Use `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzsetnextfilename{figure-name}` as shown in http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/ to speedup tikz pictures compilation for second run and navigate via `Structure` Menu left pane of editor or fold at `\begin{figure}`.